# Factoring cos, and other trig functions

Tags: fake-proofs

EDIT:
I misattributed the solution to factoring. The teacher in fact used a the trig identity:
$\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$ 
I apologise for the time wasted on my expediant attempt at factoring trig. I am now more educated on trig identities.

*Here is the original post*

---

In a proof by induction question I am doing at the moment, the solutions seem to think that:

$$\cos(k\alpha)~\cos(\alpha) = \cos((k+1)\alpha)$$ and that
$$-\sin(k\alpha)~sin(\alpha) = -sin((k+1)\alpha)$$
Does this hold true for all trig functions? Why? Would you be able to do similar factoring with addition?
Thanks

Comment: Both are wrong.

Comment: Those equations aren't true in general. You should edit your question to instead show the problem and its solution, and then we can explain what it did. (Your question currently has [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) difficulty.) My guess is you've seen an equation of the form $a+c=b+d$, not known why the author thought it too obvious to explain, and concluded $a=b$ and $c=d$ are claimed, when really it uses $a-b=d-c$.

Comment: Take $k=1$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. What do you get?

Comment: The equations are not so far from being true. $$\exp(k\alpha)\exp(\alpha)=\exp((k+1)\alpha).$$

Comment: [In fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)$$\cos(k+1)\alpha=\cos k\alpha\cos\alpha-\sin k\alpha\sin\alpha,\,\sin(k+1)\alpha=\sin k\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos k\alpha\sin\alpha.$$

Comment: Yes, I have now come to that realization. I did not take the two expressions into account as a group, but rather individually. You are the only commenter to mention this, so kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Facts checking:

$$\cos\left(2\frac\pi6\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)=\frac{\sqrt3}4$$

vs.

$$\cos\left(3\frac\pi6\right)=0.$$

---

If we combine your first equation with the well-known addition formula, we get that

$$\sin(k\alpha)\sin(\alpha)=0$$ for all $k$ and all $\alpha$ !?

Comment: or better $sin(\alpha)=0, \forall \alpha$

Comment: Yes! I agree with you this was my teacher's solution, not mine. I don't know what he did there.

Comment: @ThomasJ.: I suspect that you did not copy the solution faithfully, sorry.

Comment: yes, I agree. I think I see what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the problem ?

Comment: It was, essentially, prove de Moivre's theorem using proof by induction. See my edit.

Comment: @ThomasJ.: haha, $\exp(ik\alpha)\exp(i\alpha)=\exp(i(k+1)\alpha)$.